# How to delete particular content from a file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following JSON file which contains some content(1st line and last line) due to which I am unable to load it as a JSON file. I want to edit this file using python so that I only have the content inside {} braces and "source.value(" &  ");" are removed.

```
source.value(
{Meli:1,jack:3,rustin:4}
);


    with open('check.json', 'rb') as g:
        b=json.load(g)
    
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: `b=json.loads(g.readlines()[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how best to generalize for your specific problem since many things could change based on how these files are generated.

First off the json format requires the names to be in double quotes - {"Meli":1,"jack":3,"rustin":4}

Assuming this is fixed, we open the file, read the lines and only use json to read the second line. Remember python indexes from 0.

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    data = json.loads(lines[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion jake but i want to read the json edit the file and then update in same format like after editing jack value to 5   the file should be updated as below            source.value(
{Meli:1,jack:5,rustin:4}
);